# how to change the format of date to exported to a CSV file

Tags: csv, write

I want to write export some Information in a csv data.
One thing I don't get in in the csv data, it is the date.

Firstly when I use \today in my Latex document I get 15.January 2022, but I want it in the csv data in this way 15.01.2022.

Secondly when I just use the \today in the CSV I get this output:

**
Name, 13606, 14245.80, 15.\unhbox \voidb@x \protect \penalty @M \ December 2022,open
**

```
\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file=Info.csv
\immediate\write\file{
\Name , \theNo, \Summe, \today ,open}
\closeout\file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `datetime2` package for this. The package allows to set the date and time format and it redefines `\today` to use this format.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\DTMsetup{yearmonthsep=.,monthdaysep=.}
\DTMsetdatestyle{ddmmyyyy}
\begin{document}
\def\Name{Alice}
\newcounter{No}
\setcounter{No}{5}
\def\Summe{10}
\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file=Info.csv
\immediate\write\file{%
\Name , \theNo, \Summe, \today, open}
\closeout\file
The date is \DTMnow.
\end{document}
```

Resulting CSV:

```
Alice, 5, 10, 28.12.2021, open
```

Note that I added a `%` after `\write\file{` to prevent a space at the start of the line.

If you want to use a different format in your document (i.e., pdf output) then you can change the format again using `\DTMsetup` and/or `\DTMsetdatestyle` after writing the csv.